# Möbius transformations lines and circles

Tags: complex-analysis

I am looking for a basic outline of a proof

I know that all MT's are of the form $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$
For $c=0$, I know that lines/circles are preserved because translations and dilations do not change a line/circle from being a line/circle

But I am not sure how to prove this for all cases

<strike>My exam is actually tomorrow, so it would be great if someone could help me today :)</strike>

Comment: Do you know that MTs preserve cross-ratio?

Comment: What are you actually trying to prove? That lines and circles are mapped to lines and circles?

Comment: I believe I understood the question and I spent a decent amount of time writing up an extensive answer.

Comment: Due to the fact that this question was migrated from meta, when it was closed, it was locked (I think this should be fixed). I have unlocked it in case people want to vote to reopen.

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$
\dfrac{a\color{#C00000}{z}+b}{c\color{#C00000}{z}+d}=\frac ac+\frac1c\frac{bc-ad}{c\color{#C00000}{z}+d}\tag{1}
$$
is a composition of translation, dilation, and inversion $\left(z\mapsto\frac1z\right)$. Geometrically, it is easy to see that translation and dilation preserve circles and lines.

---

**Inversion Preserves Circles Not Passing Through The Origin**

If $|z-c|=r$ where $|c|\ne r$, then $\color{#C00000}{r^2}=(z-c)(\bar{z}-\bar{c})=\color{#C00000}{|z|^2+|c|^2-2\mathrm{Re}(z\bar{c})}$ and
$$
\begin{align}
&\left[\frac1z-\frac1c\left(\frac{|c|^2}{|c|^2-r^2}\right)\right]
\left[\frac1{\bar{z}}-\frac1{\bar{c}}\left(\frac{|c|^2}{|c|^2-r^2}\right)\right]\\
&=\frac1{|z|^2}+\frac1{|c|^2}\left(\frac{|c|^2}{|c|^2-r^2}\right)^2-2\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac1{z\bar{c}}\right)\left(\frac{|c|^2}{|c|^2-r^2}\right)\\
&=\frac1{|z|^2}+\frac1{|c|^2}\left(\frac{|c|^2}{|c|^2-r^2}\right)^2-\frac{\color{#C00000}{2\mathrm{Re}(z\bar{c})}}{|z|^2|c|^2}\left(\frac{|c|^2}{|c|^2-r^2}\right)\\
&=\frac1{|z|^2}+|c|^2\left(\frac1{|c|^2-r^2}\right)^2-\frac{\color{#C00000}{|z|^2+|c|^2-r^2}}{|z|^2}\left(\frac1{|c|^2-r^2}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{r}{|c|^2-r^2}\right)^2\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $\frac1z$ lies on the circle with
$$
\text{center}=\frac{\bar{c}}{|c|^2-r^2}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\text{radius}=\frac{r}{|c|^2-r^2}\tag{3}
$$

---

**Limiting To Circles Passing Through The Origin**

If we fix $c$ and let $r\to|c|$, the radius tends to $\infty$ while containing the following point:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\bar{c}}{|c|^2-r^2}-\frac{\bar{c}}{|c|}\frac{r}{|c|^2-r^2}
&=\frac{\bar{c}}{|c|}\frac{|c|-r}{|c|^2-r^2}\\
&=\frac{\bar{c}}{|c|}\frac1{|c|+r}\\
&\to\frac1{2c}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the circle tends to a line passing through $\dfrac1{2c}$ and perpendicular to $\bar{c}$.

---

**Lines**

Since the inverse of $z\mapsto\frac1z$ is itself, we can invert the previous section to yield that a line maps to a circle passing through the origin whose center is $\dfrac1{2p}$, where $p$ is the closest point on the line to the origin.

---

**Circles Whose Center Is The Origin And Lines Passing Through The Origin**

In the previous sections, we have ignored the problems that occur when $c=0$ and $p=0$. These cases are trivial geometrically.

Comment: Do you can give me a reference book for you answer? thanks.

Comment: Did you have a question about this answer? This topic is known as [Inversive Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry).

Comment: Hello, could you kindly elaborate on the Lines section? I am a little confused. I can invert the previous section how? By taking $|c|=r$? Wouldn't $|z-c|=|c|$ just give me the equation of a circle passing through the origin? How do I get $p$, which is the closest point on the line to the origin?

Comment: The inverse map maps a circle passing through the origin to a line not passing through the origin. The inverse of the inverse map is itself, so the inverse map maps a line not passing through the origin to a circle passing through the origin. How you find $p$ depends on the form in which the line is given.

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, if $c\neq0,$ then put $f_1(z)=z+d/c,$ $f_2(z)=1/z,$ $f_3(z)=\frac{bc-ad}{c^2}z,$ and $f_4(z)=z+a/c.$ Then $$(f_4\circ f_3\circ f_2\circ f_1)(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}.$$ So, it suffices to show that each of $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4$ maps generalized circles to generalized circles. The fact that $ad-bc\ne0$ will be essential here. The only somewhat tricky part is showing that this is true for $f_2.$ The idea is to show that lines are mapped to generalized circles through the origin and vice versa, while circles that don't pass through the origin are again mapped to circles that don't pass through the origin.

The $c=0$ case is straightforward.